# How can I tell which proxy is being used by my system from a pac file

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

My system is configured to use a pac file to select the correct proxy server based on my location in the organisation. Is it possible to run the pac file to find out which proxy is being returned and/or can I find out which proxy is being used some other way?